# Render ShapeFile/DBF with HTML5/Javascript

Tags: c#, javascript

I have a .dbf and .shp files, I can rendering in my browser using Html5 and javascript

Exist a lib c#/javascript for rendering the files?

Opensource or commercial...

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this [javascript lib](https://github.com/abstractvector/node-dbf) for abstracting the .dbf file, which might be helpful but I have never used it before. Still you would most likely need to write some C# code yourself. Here is a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11356878/2444126) and [another](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4095277/2444126) that will help guide you on down that with path for .dbf file.